# Why not render I can not access the state array?

Tags: reactjs

When I try to access the object in the array in console.log it works, but at the time of displaying on the page does not work, why?

When I use the map it works, but trying to access only one element does not.

State initialized

```
type State = {
    id_evaluation: string,
    questions: Array<{
        id: number,
        question_content_id: number,
        component: Array<{
            type_desc: string,
            content: string,
        }>,
    }>,
    current_question: number,

};
```

This work

```
class Evaluation extends Component < Props, State > {
    state = {
        id_evaluation: '',
        questions: [],
        current_question: 0,
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const id_eval = getEvaluation();

        this.setState({
            id_evaluation: String(id_eval),
            }, () => api.get("/evaluation/" + this.state.id_evaluation + "/")
                    .then(response => {
                        this.setState({
                            questions: response.data.question
                            });
                            console.log(this.state.questions[0].component[0].content)
                    })
        );
    }
```

This don't work

```
render () {
    return (

        <div>
            {this.state.questions[0].component[0].content}
        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: Which function is your console.log called from?

Comment: componentDidMount(), only for test

Comment: And how is your state initialized?

Comment: Can you post the results of your `console.log`? (partially if too long)

Comment: @MichałUrbaniak added

Comment: @GG. is string.

Comment: state is only available in components that extends from components, it's not available in function components, so make sure you are using "extends Component"

Comment: @Dado Yes, I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In initializing `state`, your `this.state.questions` is `[]`, so `this.state.questions.[0].component[0]` will cause an error. Try verifying your array first:

```
render () {
    return (

        <div>
            {this.state.questions.length > 0 ? this.state.questions.[0].component[0].content : null}
        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: I editted my answer with explanation, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

you asked why does it work, well it works because reacts lets you know the chronicle order of events that happen, and due  to that render happens before the "componentDidMount" -[source](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) , and take a look at the following  [lifecycle chart](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) .

Comment: I wanted the reason and an answer, I formulated the question wrong, but his answer helped me to understand